# Use a filter in typescript array to get a value of the first node returned

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter

I have an array coming in that can be filtered but sometimes it will return no results after the filter and other times 1 result, which is the one I need.

It goes something like this:

`this.outArray.variableTest = inArray.info.filter(q => (q.myId=== TestIdTypes.FirstId)[0].name`;

The problem is that the filter can be undefined if nothing is matched, causing an exception. If something matches then [0].name is correct and what I want. How do I check if it has length 0 or undefined? I can use any other typescript code if needed.

Comment: You can use optional chaining for this. Refer typescript docs for more details

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.find](http://Array.prototype.find()) instead of filter and use the optional chaining operator.

```js
const name = inArray.info.find(q => q.myId=== TestIdTypes.FirstId)?.name;
```

Comment: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (142:171)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
This is my error with above

Comment: If you replace the `?.` with just `.` does the error go away?  If so, you don't have a typescript loader, or you are not transpiling it to javascript before you get to that part.

Comment: I get Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the resulting item is defined or not first:

```
const filtered = inArray.info.filter(q => q.myId=== TestIdTypes.FirstId);
if (filtered.length) {
  this.outArray.variableTest = filtered[0].name;
}
```

But `.find` would really be more appropriate (and a bit more type-safe):

```
const found = inArray.info.find(q => q.myId === TestIdTypes.FirstId);
if (found) {
  this.outArray.variableTest = found.name;
}
```